# What are the requirements for the event name?

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I've written an app to publish some events via the open graph api to facebook. For most of the events this works fine. But some events facebook denies:

"OAuthException: (#100) Invalid event name specified: event_info-name"

I searched the facebook doc but I couldn't find a detailed description how the link has to look alike. I convert it to utf8 with utf8_encode (PHP). I guess that the string length is limited. If so: How long can the string be? Are there some other restrictions?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 9):

I created events with different name lengths an it seems that the max event name size is 74 characters (one with a length of 75 or more throws the "(#100) Invalid event name specified").

I think the characters in the name are pretty flexible. My titles had " and ' among others and showed up fine, without encoding, on the event page.

Comment: It would be nice if Facebook could be bothered documenting such limitations. Thank you for this.

Comment: This anwser should be accepted. Just tested it and it is correct!

Comment: More than a year later and this is still the case. Thanks!

Comment: 2014 and this is still true (also the fact they don't document it anywhere.........)

Answer (score 0):

What events do you have coded for your application in the application settings See: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/opengraph

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error, but there appears to be STOP keywords but not sure where they are. If anyone is getting this error you might also want to look at [Facebook Graph Error (#100) Invalid event name specified: event_info-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742760/facebook-graph-error-100-invalid-event-name-specified-event-info-name)

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2015 there's no character limit for event names. There's been a torrent of troll events here in Poland where people copypasted whole 100k character long books or pi number with 100k or so decimal places. The names were cut short in the event pages but in notifications page the whole names are displayed, cluttering it into oblivion.